# CSS3 Keyframe injected with javascript does not work with Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am creating a keyframe with javascript because I want to know a specific element's width in order to apply an animation style using that.

Here is the code:

```
var animation = false,
    animationstring = 'animation',
    prefix = '',
    domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms'.split(' '),
    pfx  = '',
    elm = document.querySelector('.marquee');

// Checks if the animation implementation is unprefixed
if( elm.style.animationName ) { animation = true; }

// Apply correct prefixes if the animation implementation has prefixes
if( animation === false ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++ ) {
        if( elm.style[ domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName' ] !== undefined ) {
            pfx = domPrefixes[ i ];
            animationstring = pfx + 'Animation';
            prefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
            animation = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

elm.style[ animationstring ] = 'marquee 20s linear infinite';
var keyframes = '@' + prefix + 'keyframes marquee { '+
    '0% { ' + prefix + 'transform: translateX(100%);}'+
    '100% { ' + prefix + 'transform: translateX(-' + elm.scrollWidth + 'px);}'+
    '}';

document.styleSheets[0].insertRule( keyframes, 0 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69PXa/

My problem (I think) is on row 27, I apply elm.scrollWidth as the value for translateX. This apparently breaks the keyframes in Chrome while it works as it should in Firefox. If I instead just use a fixed number the animation works.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply the CSS to your `.marquee` after you define the actual keyframes. Right now you are telling the browser to animate using keyframes that don't exist *yet*.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69PXa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this: [scrollWidth/scrollHeight give invalid dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369924/scrollwidth-scrollheight-give-invalid-dimensions)

Or this: [Is "ScrollWidth" property of a span not working on Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226296/is-scrollwidth-property-of-a-span-not-working-on-chrome)

can help you ;-)

Regards.